# customizing a table sort - classic ASP

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I must sort a table according to the header clicked (only two columns) by the user. The info is coming from a DB and then Im filling an array, the two sorting routines are working pretty well and I basically need to enable both sorting methods at a time.

I guess I should code a few javascript lines in the header, a kind of,

```
<a href="" onclick="return sortTable('Column0', 0)">ID</a>
```

And use some variable in ASP to catch the value changed from javascript but I don't know how achieve that. Handling a session won't work because it is on server side.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Ps. I'm looking into TableSorter JQuery Plugin but it looks lot more than I need and that implies to learn JQuery, I'd like to use a simplest method.

Comment: So, you have server side sort routines that work - you just want to allow the user to choose how the table is sorted by clicking one of the column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your link to something like this -

```
<a href="yourscriptname.asp?sort=id">ID</a>
```

Then in your code behind check for the QueryString parameter and sort your table accordingly. Something like -

```
If Request.QueryString("sort") = "id" Then
   'perform sort by id
ElseIf 'other sort logic

End If
```